# How do I write a query aggregation Mongo in the Spring? What am I doing wrong?

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-mvc

I've got an aggregation query in MongoDB that works when I run it directly in the shell. Here's the shell query:

```
db.game.aggregate([
 {$unwind: "$array"}, 
 {$group:{"_id" : "$array.ToId", "pointCount": {$sum:"$array.point"}}}, 
 {$project: {_id: 0, "ToId":"$_id", "pointCount": 1}}
 ])
```

I want to receive

```
List<Map<String, Integer>>
```

Where String = ToId, Integer = pointCount

That's what I'm doing

```
@Inject
private MongoTemplate mongoTemplate;

public List<Map<String, Integer>> getUsers(A array) {

    Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
        unwind("achievement"),
        group("_id", "array.ToId", "pointCount").sum("array.PointCount"),
        project("ToId", "pointCount")
    );

    AggregationResults groupResults = mongoTemplate.aggregate(
        aggregation, UserRepo.class, A.class);

    List<Map<String, Integer>> users = groupResults.getMappedResults();

    return users;
}
```

But it gives an error:
Cannot resolve method 'newAggregation(org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.UnwindOperation, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.GroupOperation.GroupOperationBuilder, org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.aggregation.ProjectionOperation)'

What am I doing wrong, please explain. Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Spring aggregation code doesn't match mongo shell query. I've provided answer to fix the compilation error. You're missing alias for sum operation.

```
Aggregation aggregation = newAggregation(
            unwind("achievement"),
            group("_id", "array.ToId", "pointCount").sum("array.PointCount").as("pointCount"),
            project("ToId", "pointCount"));
```

Comment: Thanks, Veeram. Worked perfectly